# Vim Editor Undo

Tags: vim, editor, vimrc

In Vim Editor while in normal mode when I enter 'u' it undoes all the changes made in last session instead of one line. Can anybody help regarding this.

Answer (score 2):

See [`:h undo-blocks`](https://vimhelp.org/undo.txt.html?#undo-blocks):

```
One undo command normally undoes a typed command, no matter how many changes
that command makes.  This sequence of undo-able changes forms an undo block.
Thus if the typed key(s) call a function, all the commands in the function are
undone together.
```

And further down:

```
To do the opposite, use a new undo block for the next change, in Insert mode
use CTRL-G u.  This is useful if you want an insert command to be undoable in
parts.
```

If you *always* want line-wise undo blocks, you can use something like:

```
:inoremap <cr> <c-g>u<cr>
```

which will automatically include `<C-g>u` whenever you press <kbd>Enter</kbd> in Insert mode. Then `u` will undo the last line you entered if you entered multiple lines at once.

Answer (score 0):

The keystroke for this is Shift-u (i.e. capital U).

Unlike 'u', 'U' conducts an 'undo' operation on the line you are in, and is considered an operation in itself (meaning it can be 'undone' by a 'u' command).

Type `:help U` in vim while in Normal mode to see the documentation for the 'U' command in more detail.